# Does ASP Identity not contain a login function for using the email and password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, asp.net-identity

When created a project with MVC5 and Identity the template project gives login features using:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Username, model.Password);
```

But I want users to login using their emails and passwords.

Am I therefore forced to use the following, without creating my own login functions or is there a better way?

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
var username = user.UserName;
var userOK = await UserManager.FindAsync(username, model.Password);
```

Basically I'm asking how do I do this in one DB call.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own SimpleMembershipProvider (or to write code like what you posted) why don't you simply enforce username to be their e-mail address during registration?

Comment: thats the default. I cant use that though, it messes around with my scripts due to the @. I assume by this then I'll have to write my own provider? *sighs*

Comment: Just change your login controller, they write their e-mail too, right? Then don't ask for username and fill it with e-mail in the POST method. Otherwise if for any reason it's not possible I'd go with a custom provider, you have to override just few methods.